# Browser unable to post and google map javascript api key unauthorize

Tags: asp.net-mvc, macos, google-maps-api-3, browser, http-post

I am having an issue with my colleague's Macbook Air that seem to be performing in a very unusual way with http call and Js.

Both browsers chrome and safari is having an issue in doing a http post request with attachment. When testing with log at the post method. It seem to me, it  actually did not manage to post to the URL but instead it return "Runtime error" on his side. I have tested it with others PC and laptop. Every devices were working correctly but just not his Macbook.

His browser has loading issue too that require him to load more than 1 min for a simple HTTP get page. All other devices i have is able to load the web in less than a sec using the same WiFI, i even tested it using other colleagues PC and laptop and is the same result.

Another thing was loading google map api on my company web. All my colleagues and myself are able load the map. However he is receiving RefererNotAllowedMapError, which require me to set the referrer on google console api. Which i already did very long ago. His browser has javascript enabled too.

I really not very sure what wrong with his laptop. His Macbook air is just 1 year old.

Comment: Try restarting in safe mode and see if the errors persist https://support.apple.com/en-sg/HT201262